# Setting opacity on image causes an overlapping element's box-shadow to go away

Tags: css, opacity

The following CSS, applied to an `<a>` and a `<div>` residing in individual `<tr>`▶`<td>` elements in a `<table>` (with `border-collapse` and `td { padding: 0px; }` set), works as expected:

```
a {
    background-image: url("http://ibin.co/19rwR69EOigr");
    height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: #000 0px 0px 13px;
}
```

If I apply *any* opacity to the `<a>`, the browser's internal layering seems to break horribly.

[image: Comparison]
Note that the test picture's last pixel sits within the `<div>`'s `box-shadow`, even in the first example. *(And it says `opacity = ".99"`, if you can't see it in the image >.>)*

Is this possibly a rendering bug that's managed to creep into both Firefox *and* Chrome? :P

**[See what opens and shuts in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbAYU/1/)**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Quite Simple.

### Thank you for clean formatting.

**Change `opaque ID` to this:**

```
#opaque {
    opacity: .99;
    z-index:-10;
    position:relative;
}
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/GbAYU/3/

---

What is happening is whenever `opacity` is set, the back-end method of **CSS3** to interpret it throws some pretty **wild** `z-index`'s.

Just set it to stack **behind** the other elements and all will work fine for you.

`position:relative;` - Cause otherwise it wouldn't accept your `z-index` property.

`z-index:-10;` - So that it places it behind the `z-index` of **0** of your other objects.

---

## EDIT:

**The default value of HTML elements does not support `static` as an object that `z-index` will apply to, hence the `position` declaration.**

And it totally does with `absolute`, `fixed`, `relative`, or `inherit`, **but not `static`.**

Comment: Wow, thanks. Fast!
I was trying `z-index: -1` at one point, which wasn't working... why is the `position:relative` important?

Comment: [That works too](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/GbAYU/5/). I just like keeping my z-indexes in values of 10 or greater. You missed setting the `position` :-)

Comment: _*learns that `z-index` doesn't work without `position:relative`*_

Comment: And it totally does with `absolute`, `fixed`, `relative`, or `inherit`, but not `static`.